# Getting "400 Bad Request" response when trying to update Jira issue programmatically

Tags: c#, jira

I am trying to update status of an issue in JIRA using C# code. I found various curl codes for the same, but since I am unfamiliar to curl, I converted the code to C#.

I am getting '400 Bad Request' error. Looked over the internet to find it's mainly because of the JSON that we pass to update the issue, so did a bit of changes in there. Now I'm simply trying to update summary of the issue. But somehow failing to do so.

Also I am new to C# and Jira environment, it would be great if you could help me out with finding the error and resolving it. Or if I am missing something in the code?

See code below:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PUT"), "https://<host-url>/rest/api/2/issue/<issue-key>"))
                {
                    var username = "<username>";
                    var password = "<API Key>";
                    string data = @"{'update' : {'summary' : [{'set' : 'Big block Chevy'}]}}";
                    var base64authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}"));
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Bearer {base64authorization}");

                    request.Content = new StringContent($"{data}");
                    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

                    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                    Console.WriteLine(response);
                }
            }
```

Comment: JSON uses `"` not `'`. Your JSON is not valid. Use a JSON serializer (e.g. System.Text.Json or Json.NET) to construct your request objects to avoid simple mistakes like this.

Comment: Thank you @Llama for pointing that out. It resolved "BadRequest" error. Somehow, now I am getting "404 Not found" error. Do you have any idea on this? I'm sorry if the question seems too naive, I am very new here.

Comment: I'd guess the issue doesn't exist, or you have the wrong URL slightly. You'd have to check your data and the API reference.